# cakephp Table for model was not found in datasource default

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have just a table on my database named "ficha_seg".
The name of my model file is "Ficha.php" and the name of the controller is "FichasController.php".

So, why i'm getting the error:

```
Error: Table fichas for model Ficha was not found in datasource default.
```

after configured my index() method of controller like this:

```
 public function index() {
    $this->set('ficha_seg', $this->Ficha->find('all'));
}
```

Comment: is there any table named 'fichas' in your database ? Because we have to make table name fichas on behalf of model name Ficha.php

Comment: no, it's "ficha_seg". It should be "fichas"?

Comment: alter the table name with fichas

Comment: but what if i wanted to access a different table? is it because this method is the index? or in the others i will have the same problem and can't access other tables?

Comment: yes you can ... just write the query in your model file
like $this->ModelName->query("your query");

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By default, the model uses the lowercase, plural form of the model’s class name for the database table name.

If you need to use another table name for your model, you can use the `useTable` attribute:

```
class Ficha extends AppModel 
{
    public $useTable = 'ficha_seg';
}
```

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usetable
and [Model conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions) in the Cookbook

Comment: This answer will be relevant for few http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716004/cakephp-database-table-missing-datasource-default

Answer (score 5):

To follow CakePHP conventions your table name should be in plural: `ficha_segs` and your model name should be 'FichaSeg'.

If you don't want to follow it for any reason, do what @nlcO says.

Comment: Thanks Steve, one way or another now i know how to use both "options".