# CakePHP Name convention Issue

Tags: cakephp

```
Cakephp V. 2.5
```

My database table name is `group_key_persons` and My Model Name is `GroupKeyPerson` when i am writing this code to fetching the data.

```
$this->loadModel ( 'GroupKeyPerson' );
$data = $this->GroupKeyPerson->find('all');
pr($data);
```

It return an error :

```
Missing Database Table

Error: Table group_key_people for model GroupKeyPerson was not found in datasource default.
```

But i am preety sure database table is exist. but why the hell is people comes from in my table.??

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511136/cakephp-table-for-model-was-not-found-in-datasource-default/13511623

Comment: Too late to edit my comment: my previous link can be useful if you can't change the table name. But if you can, probably just follow ADmad advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plural of "person" is "people" not "persons". So your table name should "group_key_people"

Comment: If you ever need to check how Cake pluralises words there's an online tool for testing the inflector: http://inflector.cakephp.org/.